# SSH - Add public keys to server after disabling PasswordAuthentication

Tags: ssh, authentication

How can I add public keys to a host from unauthorized clients after disabling `PasswordAuthentication`?

I have one client registered to the host via public key. I need to add additional clients. Do I need to turn on `PasswordAuthentication` every time I need to add a new key?

Is there a different scheme for accomplishing this task that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't turn on `PasswordAuthentication` just to add a new key.  Authenticate with the key which is already authorized in order to upload the new public key.  Add a new line to the `authorized_keys` file containing the new public key.  (The `authorized_keys` file contains one public key per line.  For example:

```
# Copy new public key across
scp new_key.pub server:~
# Shell into the server, again using existing key to auth
ssh server
# Append (using >>) the new public key to authorized_keys:
cat new_key.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
# Clean up
rm new_key.pub
```

Now try authenticating with the private part of the new key.

However, if you've switched off `PasswordAuthentication` without adding any public keys in the first place, you'll need to look for another way to gain access to the server.  Possibly at the physical terminal, or if it's cloud based investigate if the provider has a console login available through the control panel.

Comment: I have one authorized key for remote access to a physical terminal already, so no issues there. Does this mean all authenticated users have the ability to add other public keys? Or should it be structured in a way that only one user may add new keys (could be an opinion, but I'm looking for security here)?

Comment: The `authorized_keys` file by default will be owned by the unix user who's home directory it exists in, and should have `group/other rwx` permissions disabled.  A unix user could add a new key to their own `authorized_keys` file, and any outsider with that key could authenticate as them.  This has the same effect as giving away their private key.  However, the permissions on these files by default should prevent bob adding a public key (for which he owns the private part) to alice's `authorized_keys` and authenticating as her.

Comment: Also private keys have a passphrase for a reason: If the key is stolen the attacker still needs to know the passphrase to use the key.  For this reason your users should really generate their own private/public keypair, and send you the public half, at which point you add it to their `authorized_keys` as part of the account creation process.

Comment: It makes sense that the key is stored on the server for the *server* to authenticate instead of reversing that and putting one key on the server and distributing the server's public key to each client.